# Primefaces Showcase autocomplete countryService @inject problem (Primefaces 8.0, JSF 2.3, TomEE-wepprofile)

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete, cdi, inject

Trying to get "Primefaces Showcase autocomplete" running I'm facing a problem that "CountryService.java" won't load. I copied it from (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml?jfwid=52f7c). It looks like it's caused by the "**@Inject private CountryService countryService**;" not functioning.

In autoCompleteView.java I added a printline to the method **completeText**:

public List **completeText**(String query) {
System.out.println(thisClassName + ": completeText (1) - " + query + " / " + **countryService**);}

When running it shows this: "AutoCompleteView: completeText (1) - ned / null", meaning '**countryService**' has not been initialized. Could it be an **CDI issue?** I'm using 'tomee-8.0.6-webprofile' that according to documentation should support CDI! Or must I install CDI2.0 seperately into my java library lists?

I tried the @BalusC solution of: [How to inject FacesContext with JSF 2.3 and TomEE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846590/how-to-inject-facescontext-with-jsf-2-3-and-tomee)

Maybe something is missing in my installation? :

Eclipse 18-12;

Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/9.0.41 (8.0.6);

JSF2.3;

myfaces2.3;

Primefaces 8.0;

Could anyone help me please? I would appreciate that very much!

Comment: Note that the PF showcase is running on PF 10.0.0-RC1, not on 8.0

Comment: @Petter Friberg, yes this is the right solution! thx for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Found the right answer in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44411810/1839439)

I added "beans.xml" to my WEB-INF directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">

</beans>
```